# Cloud9's database management with External DB management tool

Tags: mysql, remote-access, cloud9-ide

Is there a way to use Database management tool like a Sequel Pro remote connect to Cloud9 IDE's MySQL database

Thanks

Comment: did you finally achieve it?

Comment: @GestudioCloudBecause this is a quite old issue if I remember correctly I've changed to another Cloud IDE instead. I'm sorry that I cannot answer my own question

Comment: thanks! I have just discovered that they have phpmyadmin... :D   https://community.c9.io/t/setting-up-phpmyadmin/1723

Answer (score 0):

Since all Cloud9 workspaces only forward one port (8080), I don't think this will be practical since you'd want to run your app as well. However, you could possibly make MySQL listen to 0.0.0.0:8080 and try connecting like that.